# Transformar vsix en dll. Quiero añadir un .VSIX en mi código

Tags: c#

No se si es una locura, pero quiero que el paquete de Visual Studio Installer project este dentro de mi código y no en exe.
Es decir que si yo paso el código de mi programa no tenga que hacer que otra persona tenga que entrar en Tools-- extensions...  y que tenga que descargarlo.

Hay alguna forma de incluir el Installer Projects en mi trabajo?

Gracias!

Comment: Diría que no. Y no termino de verle la utilidad la verdad...el código no tiene que ver con las extensiones que otro programador quiera/necesite/prefiera en su entorno de programación. Además... _si yo paso el código de mi programa_ ..el codigo es texto, como quieres meter un instalador ahi? Tal vez soy yo el que no entiendo tu pregunta :)

Comment: lo que tu dices, es que quieres tener tu código en un repositorio o no, pero cuando alguien habrá tu solución le diga que debe descargar esa extension?

Comment: Hola Ramiro,  exacto  quiero hacer lo más fácilmente posible la instalación de la aplicacion ^^.